# Function pointer to global operator compiles on VC++ while clang gives an error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, friend, clang++

I am trying to get the following code to compile on clang, but it fails with the following error:

```
error: no member named 'operator<' in the global namespace
```

I tried compiling the visual studio code with /Za to switch to standard conformance, but it still seems to accept it. Enlighten me please.

```
struct A
{
  int m_test;
  A(int test)
    : m_test(test)
  {

  }

  friend bool operator<(A left, A right);
};

int main()
{
  typedef bool(*TCompare)(A,A);
  TCompare compare = &::operator<;

  compare(9,7);
}
```

VC++ output: https://godbolt.org/g/LAz56n

Clang output: https://godbolt.org/g/zC2InO

Comment: Where do you *define* the operator function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang is correct. For your sample code, the name `operator<` introduced by [friend declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces) does become the member of the global namespace, but it's **not visible** to name lookup. It can only be found by [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), but ADL only applies to function-call expressions, while `&::operator<` is not.

> Names introduced by friend declarations within a non-local class `X`
>   become members of the innermost enclosing namespace of `X`, but they do
>   not become visible to lookup (neither unqualified nor qualified)
>   unless a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope, either
>   before or after the class definition. Such name may be found through
>   ADL which considers both namespaces and classes.

To fix it you have to add a matching declaration at global namespace scope. e.g.

```
struct A
{
  int m_test;
  A(int test)
    : m_test(test)
  {

  }

  friend bool operator<(A left, A right);
};

// add a matching declaration at namespace scope
bool operator<(A left, A right);

int main()
{
  typedef bool(*TCompare)(A,A);
  TCompare compare = &::operator<;

  compare(9,7);
}

bool operator<(A left, A right) { 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a VC++ bug. The code is invalid.

A friend declaration doesn't introduce the declared name to the global namespace. You still need to declare it outside of the class.

Comment: You could well mention the history here, with [friend name injection](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0777.pdf).

Comment: Uhm, the link (which I ripped from Wikipedia) seems to be not very relevant. But in short, Visual C++ is probably allowing this for backwards compatibility. The rules have changed.

Comment: Apparently the rule change came about during the standardization process, after the Annotated Reference Manual roughly 1989 but before the first standard in 1998. However, my copy of the ARM is a dead tree book which resides in a paper box in big pile of such boxes far from here, so I can't practically check this.